# Fetch request infinite pending in a new tab in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, fetch

In my react project Chrome will never send fetch requests if I open a link in a new tab:

[chrome network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1eQ0.png)
[chrome console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9sS6.png)

Here is standard fetch:

```
let h = new Headers();
    h.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    h.append('X-Custom-Header', '123');

    let req = new Request(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: h, //заголовки
        mode: 'cors'
    });
    fetch(req).then((response) => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            console.log(response);
        }
        return response;
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((items) => console.log(items.data))
```

I tried to do this in dev console:

```
async function load() {
        let response = await fetch('/somesite.com', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Custom-Header': '123'
            },
            mode: 'cors'
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }

    load();
```

XHR requests doesn't work too. Console log is clean, no mistakes. In Mozilla/Opera/Safari everything is fine.

With disabled `chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors` Chrome will send requests correctly. But it doesn't solve issue for all users.
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set correctly.

I don't understand what is wrong...

Useful links:
`https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11089651?hl=en`
`https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5768642492891136`
`https://www.chromium.org/Home/loading/oor-cors`

Comment: can you share your console logs ?

Comment: Might have to look into adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` in your API response header

Comment: @Hemanath I was try to use `console.log` on `fetch('/somesite', { body }).then(response => console.log('test') return response)` and console was clear - nothing :(

Comment: @ShawnYap Server is already use this: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'`

Comment: @MashiruSesuke can you please share the screenshot of the console tab in chrome dev tools like you shared the chrome network tab ?

Comment: @Hemanath ok, just a sec - added

Comment: Could it be breaking on error? You can "deactivate breakponts" in deftools sources tab

Comment: @HMR it couldn't. If it was an error, then it must catching to console. But console is clear :(